# symfony: question about a choice widget

Tags: php, select, input, symfony1

I have a choice widget in a form:

```
$years = range(14,130);
$this->widgetSchema['age'] = new sfWidgetFormSchema();
foreach (array('from', 'to') as $value)
{ 
    $this->widgetSchema['age'][$value] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
        'label' => $value,
            'choices' => array_merge(array('' =>  '-'),array_combine($years,$years)))); 
}
```

If i choose for example 14 and in the action that receives the form is written something like this:

```
var_dump($valores_widgets['age']['from']);
```

that shows 0. But I expected 14.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation of `array_merge`:

> If, however, the arrays contain
>   numeric keys, the later value will not
>   overwrite the original value, but will
>   be appended.
>
> If all of the arrays contain only
>   numeric keys, the resulting array is
>   given incrementing keys starting from
>   zero.

A quick test:

```
maerlyn@biliskner:~$ php --run '$years=range(14,16);var_dump(array_merge(array("" =>  "-"), array_combine($years,$years)));'

array(4) {
  [""]=>
  string(1) "-"
  [0]=>
  int(14)
  [1]=>
  int(15)
  [2]=>
  int(16)
}
```

So your $years array gets reindexed during the merge. When using the `+` operator instead:

```
maerlyn@biliskner:~$ php --run '$years=range(14,16);var_dump(array("" =>  "-") + array_combine($years,$years));'

array(4) {
  [""]=>
  string(1) "-"
  [14]=>
  int(14)
  [15]=>
  int(15)
  [16]=>
  int(16)
}
```